# Animação do input radio(materialize) não acompanha as propriedades

Tags: jquery, materialize, radiobutton

Estou tentando manipular o input radio dinamicamente e a propriedade(checked) do elemento esta sendo manipuladas corretamente, porém a animação do campo não acompanha essa dinâmica, na primeira vez sim, porém das outras não. **Faço uso do framework materialize**

Um amostra do que ocorre:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#b1').click(function() {
    $('#1').attr('checked', '');
    $('#2, #3').removeAttr('checked');
  });
  $('#b2').click(function() {
    $('#2').attr('checked', '');
    $('#1, #3').removeAttr('checked');
  });
  $('#b3').click(function() {
    $('#3').attr('checked', '');
    $('#1, #2').removeAttr('checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
  <title>Erro input radio</title>

  <meta content="charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
</header>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col offset-s6 s6">

      <p>
        <input id="1" type="radio" name="polonia">
        <label for="1">Um</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input id="2" type="radio" name="polonia">
        <label for="2">Dois</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input id="3" type="radio" name="polonia">
        <label for="3">Três</label>
      </p>

      <button id="b1" class="btn">1</button>
      <button id="b2" class="btn">2</button>
      <button id="b3" class="btn">3</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `+1` pelo bom exemplo do problema para podermos testar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar a propriedade do elemento DOM `.checked` (ver segundo exemplo) em vêz de atributos de HTML. Com jQuery (ver primeiro exemplo) isso faz-se com o `.prop()`.

Em ambos os casos não precisas de remover do anteriormente selecionado uma vez que em HTML inputs `radio` já fazem isso automáticamente.

O segundo exemplo é mais abrangente e flexivel pois não está limitado a *N* elementos nem às suas IDs.

Usando o `.prop()` do jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#b1').click(function() {
    $('#1').prop('checked', true);
  });
  $('#b2').click(function() {
    $('#2').prop('checked', true);
  });
  $('#b3').click(function() {
    $('#3').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
  <title>Erro input radio</title>

  <meta content="charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
</header>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col offset-s6 s6">

      <p>
        <input id="1" type="radio" name="polonia">
        <label for="1">Um</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input id="2" type="radio" name="polonia">
        <label for="2">Dois</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input id="3" type="radio" name="polonia">
        <label for="3">Três</label>
      </p>

      <button id="b1" class="btn">1</button>
      <button id="b2" class="btn">2</button>
      <button id="b3" class="btn">3</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Segundo exemplo, usando as posição dos elementos no DOM, ie tendo em conta a organização do HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btns = $('.row .btn');
  var inputs = $('.row [type="radio"]');
  btns.each(function(i) {
    $(this).on('click', (function(input) {
      return function() {
        input.checked = true;
      }
    })(inputs[i]));
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
  <title>Erro input radio</title>

  <meta content="charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
</header>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col offset-s6 s6">

      <p>
        <input id="1" type="radio" name="polonia">
        <label for="1">Um</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input id="2" type="radio" name="polonia">
        <label for="2">Dois</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input id="3" type="radio" name="polonia">
        <label for="3">Três</label>
      </p>

      <button id="b1" class="btn">1</button>
      <button id="b2" class="btn">2</button>
      <button id="b3" class="btn">3</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```